# Apply Validation Function To All TextFields and Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am a newbie in Javascript and can't figure out how to make my function work for both radio buttons and textfields.

Below is the HTML code for the form

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" name="cascader"
 onsubmit="prepareEventHandlers()" id="cascader">   
 <div class="TargetCenter">   <p><strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Target Center</strong>  </p>
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="TargetCountry" value="allCountries" id="TargetCountry" />
   All Countries</label>
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="TargetCountry" value="France" id="TargetCountry" />
   France</label>
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Bolivia" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />
   Bolivia</label>
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="North America" id="CheckboxGroup1_2" />
   North America</label>
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="United Kingdom" id="CheckboxGroup1_3" />
   United Kingdom</label>
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Baltics" id="CheckboxGroup1_4" />
   Baltics</label>
 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Slovakia" id="CheckboxGroup1_5" />
   Slovakia</label>

 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Sweden" id="CheckboxGroup1_6" />
   Sweden</label>

 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Switzerland" id="CheckboxGroup1_7" />
   Switzerland</label>
 <br />   </div>  <!--end of Cascade Target-->  <div class="CascadeCategory">    <strong>
 <span class="asterisk">*</span>Cascade Category: </strong>    <label>
  <input type="radio" name="cascadeCategory" value="Process" id="CascadeCategory_0" />
  Process</label>    <label>
  <input type="radio" name="cascadeCategory" value="Training" id="CascadeCategory_1" />
  Training</label>    <label>
  <input type="radio" name="cascadeCategory" value="Knowledge" id="CascadeCategory_2"/> Knowledge</label>    <br />     </div> <!--end
  of Cascade Category-->  <div class="ProcessTitle"><strong><span
  class="asterisk">*</span>Process Title:    <input name="textfld"
  type="text" id="processTitle" iname="processTitle"
  onkeypress="checkFieldValue()"  />  </strong><span
  id="errorMessage"></span></div>  <!--end of Process Title-->  <div
  class="CascadeType">    <strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Cascade
  Type:</strong> <label>   <input type="radio" name="cascadeType"
  value="Release" />   Release</label>    <label>
  <input type="radio" name="cascadeType" value="Update" id="CascadeType_1" />
  Update</label>    <label>
  <input type="radio" name="cascadeType" value="Reminder" id="CascadeType_2" />
  Reminder</label>    <br /> </div>   <!--end of Cascade Type--> <div class="QuickDescr">    <strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Quick
 Description: </strong><br /> <br /><textarea name="textfld" cols="70%"
  rows="5" id="quickDescr"></textarea><span id="errorMessage2"></span>
  </div>   <!--end of Quick Description--> <div class="Details">
  <strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Details: </strong><br /><br/>
 <textarea name="details" cols="70%" rows="10" id="details"></textarea> </div>
 <!--end of Description--> <div class="DueDate"> <strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Due
 Date:</strong> <input type="text" class="Due" name="DueDate"
 placeholder="mm.dd.yyyy" />  <span
 class="DueDateFormat">(mm.dd.yyyy)</span></div> <!--end of Due date-->
 <br /> <br /> <br /> <input name="Submit" type="submit"
 class="CascadeButton" value="Send Cascade"  />

 <input type="reset" value="Clear Fields" class="ResetButton" />
 </form>
```

Below is the Javascript I applied for the processTitle textfield.

```
function prepareEventHandlers() {
    document.getElementById("cascader").onsubmit = function() {
        // prevent a form from submitting if no email.
        if (document.getElementById("processTitle").value == "") {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please enter a value";
            // to STOP the form from submitting
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            document.getElementById('processTitle').style.cssText = 'background-color: #f4fc99;';
            // to turn the field background color
            return false;
        } else {
            // reset and allow the form to submit
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
        }
    };
}
// when the document loads
window.onload =  function() {
    prepareEventHandlers();
};
// Changes the field color onFocus
function checkFieldValue() {
    if (document.getElementById("processTitle").value != "") {
            document.getElementById('processTitle').style.cssText = 'background-color: #FFF;';
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
        }
    else document.getElementById('processTitle').style.cssText = 'background-color: #f4fc99;';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a little function to check if one of the radio buttons is selected. See checkRequiredRadioButtons at the bottom of the javascript. Currently I just linked it to your existing validation-failure code.

```js
function prepareEventHandlers() {
        document.getElementById("cascader").onsubmit = function() {
          // prevent a form from submitting if no email.
          if (document.getElementById("processTitle").value == "" || !checkRequiredRadioButtons('cascadeType')) {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Please enter a value";
            // to STOP the form from submitting
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            document.getElementById('processTitle').style.cssText = 'background-color: #f4fc99;';
            // to turn the field background color
            return false;
          } else {
            // reset and allow the form to submit
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
            return true;
          }
        };
      }
      // when the document loads
    window.onload = function() {
      prepareEventHandlers();
    };
     // Changes the field color onFocus
    function checkFieldValue() {
      if (document.getElementById("processTitle").value != "") {
        document.getElementById('processTitle').style.cssText = 'background-color: #FFF;';
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
      } else document.getElementById('processTitle').style.cssText = 'background-color: #f4fc99;';
    }

    function checkRequiredRadioButtons(buttonsName) {
      var buttonSet = document.getElementsByName(buttonsName);

      for(i = 0; i < buttonSet.length; i++){
          if(buttonSet[i].checked == true)
            return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

```html
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post" name="cascader" onsubmit="prepareEventHandlers()" id="cascader">
  <div class="TargetCenter">
    <p><strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Target Center</strong> 
    </p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="TargetCountry" value="allCountries" id="TargetCountry" />All Countries</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="TargetCountry" value="France" id="TargetCountry" />France
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Bolivia" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />Bolivia
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="North America" id="CheckboxGroup1_2" />North America</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="United Kingdom" id="CheckboxGroup1_3" />United Kingdom</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Baltics" id="CheckboxGroup1_4" />Baltics
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Slovakia" id="CheckboxGroup1_5" />Slovakia
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Sweden" id="CheckboxGroup1_6" />Sweden
    </label>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup1" value="Switzerland" id="CheckboxGroup1_7" />Switzerland
    </label>
    <br />
  </div>
  <!--end of Cascade Target-->
  <div class="CascadeCategory"> <strong>
 <span class="asterisk">*</span>Cascade Category: </strong> 
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="cascadeCategory" value="Process" id="CascadeCategory_0" />Process
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="cascadeCategory" value="Training" id="CascadeCategory_1" />Training
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="cascadeCategory" value="Knowledge" id="CascadeCategory_2" />Knowledge</label>
    <br />
  </div>
  <!--end
  of Cascade Category-->
  <div class="ProcessTitle"><strong><span
  class="asterisk">*</span>Process Title:    <input name="textfld"
  type="text" id="processTitle" iname="processTitle"
  onkeypress="checkFieldValue()"  />  </strong><span id="errorMessage"></span>
  </div>
  <!--end of Process Title-->
  <div class="CascadeType"> <strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Cascade
  Type:</strong> 
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="cascadeType" value="Release" />Release</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="cascadeType" value="Update" id="CascadeType_1" />Update
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="cascadeType" value="Reminder" id="CascadeType_2" />Reminder
    </label>
    <br />
  </div>
  <!--end of Cascade Type-->
  <div class="QuickDescr"> <strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Quick
 Description: </strong>
    <br />
    <br />
    <textarea name="textfld" cols="70%" rows="5" id="quickDescr"></textarea><span id="errorMessage2"></span>
  </div>
  <!--end of Quick Description-->
  <div class="Details">
    <strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Details: </strong>
    <br />
    <br/>
    <textarea name="details" cols="70%" rows="10" id="details"></textarea>
  </div>
  <!--end of Description-->
  <div class="DueDate"> <strong><span class="asterisk">*</span>Due
 Date:</strong> 
    <input type="text" class="Due" name="DueDate" placeholder="mm.dd.yyyy" /> <span class="DueDateFormat">(mm.dd.yyyy)</span>
  </div>
  <!--end of Due date-->
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="CascadeButton" value="Send Cascade" />

  <input type="reset" value="Clear Fields" class="ResetButton" />
</form>
```

If you're trying to dynamically determine whether you have a textbox or a radio button, you can call Element.getAttribute('type') and compare. As in:

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++){
    if(allInputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'radio'){
        //Do radio button handling
    } else if(allInputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text'){
        //Do textbox handling  
    }
}
```

However, if you do that you need to be aware that for radio buttons you're going to iterate over all the radio buttons in the group, checked and unchecked alike. As well as your submit and reset buttons.

Comment: Thanks for all the advise. Both contributed to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try the javascript **[getElementsByTagName() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)**:

```
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
  if(x[i].value==""){
   x[i].style.backgroundColor="red";
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the advise. Both contributed to what I need.